# Segmentation Fault caused by realloc?

Tags: c, realloc, dma

Hei, I was trying to solve this school exercise..

Write a program that keeps reading in character strings and concatenates them (adds them to a single character string). the concatenation should take place in a function that returns 1 if successful or 0 if it fails. for memory allocation use only realloc!

I don't receive any error while debugging the program, but when I try to run the program, after I insert the string the only thing that appears is "Segmentation Fault", what could it be? This is the code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int cat(char **, char *);

int main(void)
{
  char string[51];
  char *output=NULL;
  char choice;
  do
  {
    printf("Please enter a string [<50 chars]: ");
    fgets(string,50,stdin);
    if(string[strlen(string)-1]=='\n') /* if newline was read as well */
      string[strlen(string)-1]=0;      /* discard it */
    if(cat(&output,string))
      printf("\n\nThe string now contains:\n%s\n",output);
    else
    {
      printf("error: memory (re-)allocation failed!\n\n");
      return 1; /* exit with error */ 
    }
    printf("Continue? (y/n) - ");
    fgets(string,3,stdin); /* read input from keyboard - leave a safety buffer to account for read newline */
    choice=string[0]; /* use the first character from the previous read as the choice */
  } while(choice=='y' || choice=='Y');

  free(output);
  return 0;
}

int cat(char **dest, char *src)
{

  int i;
  int length1=strlen(src);
  int length2=strlen(*dest);
  int length3=length1+length2;
  *dest=(char*)realloc(NULL,sizeof(*src));
  printf("%p", *dest);
  if(*dest==NULL) return 0; /* if allocation failed */
  for(i=0;i<=length3;i++)
  {
      if(i<=length1)
        (*dest)[i]=(*dest)[i];
      else
        (*dest)[i]=(src)[i];
  }
  free(src);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You can reduce your `choice` compares by using `toupper()` or `tolower()`,  example: `toupper(choice) == 'Y')`.

Comment: `free(src)` - you try to free the array `string` here. Also, `*dest=(char*)realloc(NULL,sizeof(*src));` - this allocates space for 1 `char`.

Comment: You went to all the trouble to find the new length (but forgot the terminator) and then fell on your sword with `*dest=(char*)realloc(NULL,sizeof(*src));` which will allocate **1 byte**. Also, pass the pointer variable itself, perhaps with a value of `NULL` if you have not yet allocated any memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least 5 issues with your code:

1) You should `free` only what you allocated yourself on the heap. Don't `free(src)` because what you pass in `src` points to stack memory (`char string[51];` is freed automatically).

2) you probably meant to reallocate `dest`, and 3) you meant to allocate memory the size of `length3` (+1 null-terminator).

```
    *dest=(char*)realloc(*dest, length3 + 1);
```

4) `strlen(*dest)` will crash when `*dest` is NULL initially.

```
    int length2=(*dest)?strlen(*dest):0;
```

5) I don't think your for-loop is correct. It won't concatenate the strings, your offset calculation is off.

Comment: I did what you said...But still it gave me the same error

Comment: By assigning the return value of `realloc()` directly to the pointer to the memory being reallocated, you risk losing a pointer to the data, and gaining a memory leak. If `realloc()` fails, a null pointer is returned. You should store the return value in a temporary pointer and then check to be certain that the allocation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of the pointer `output` is NULL. However inside the function there is no check that the pointer is equal to NULL. So applying the function `strlen` to the pointer results in undefined behavior.

Also you need to reserve one more character for the terminating zero.

The memory is not reallocated correctly in the function. Moreover `sizeof( *src )` is equal to one byte.

This statement

```
  if(i<=length1)
    (*dest)[i]=(*dest)[i];
```

does not make great sense. The reallocated memory provided that it was reallocated correctly already contains the original string.

You shall not free the pointer `src` because it does not point to a dynamically allocated memory.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cat( char **dest, const char *src )
{
    size_t n = strlen( src ) + ( *dest == NULL ? 0 : strlen( *dest ) );

    char *tmp = realloc( *dest, n + 1 );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( *dest == NULL ) *tmp = '\0';
        *dest = tmp;

        while ( *tmp ) ++tmp;

        while ( ( *tmp++ = *src++ ) );
    }       

    return success;
}   

#define N   50

int main(void) 
{
    char *output = NULL;
    char choice = 'n';

    do
    {
        char string[N];


        printf( "Please enter a string [<%d chars]: ", N );
        fgets( string, sizeof( string ),stdin );

        string[strcspn( string, "\n" )] = '\0';

        if ( cat( &output, string ) )
        {
            printf( "\nThe string now contains:\n\"%s\"\n\n", output );
        }           
        else
        {
            printf( "error: memory (re-)allocation failed!\n\n" );
            return 1; /* exit with error */ 
        }

        printf( "Continue? (y/n) - " );
        fgets( string, 3, stdin ); /* read input from keyboard - leave a safety buffer to account for read newline */
        choice = string[0]; /* use the first character from the previous read as the choice */
    } while ( choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y' );

    free( output );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Please enter a string [<50 chars]: Hi Stefano Feltre

The string now contains:
"Hi Stefano Feltre"

Continue? (y/n) - y
Please enter a string [<50 chars]: 

The string now contains:
"Hi Stefano Feltre "

Continue? (y/n) - y
Please enter a string [<50 chars]: Let's learn C

The string now contains:
"Hi Stefano Feltre Let's learn C"

Continue? (y/n) - n
```

Comment: @Stefano Feltre See the demonstrative program in my answer.

Comment: Mmmh...Wouldn't be possible to make it without using macro?
Moreover, for this exercise i need to keep the function as:

int cat(char **dest, char *src)

I can't modify this.
And i don't really understand why you need the variable *tmp...can't we directly use the variable *dest for the realloc?
Thx

Comment: @StefanoFeltre  The macro introduces name instead of a magic number 50. It is always better to used named constants instead of magic numbers. If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you can substitute it for a constant variable. For example const size_t N = 50; You shall declare the second parameter with the qualifier const. It is contract between the function and the client that uses the function that the parameter will not be changed within the function. The variable tmp is needed because realloc can return NULL. In this case the value of dest will be lost.

Comment: @StefanoFeltre See also the comment of  David Bowling to the previous post.